# change ul style after applying yui reset + base

Tags: html, css

See http://jsfiddle.net/PdZrt/

Basically I have applied the yui reset and base and am the trying to seperately style a ul for a menu. The li's pick up the style but the ul doesn't appear too.

Any ideas?

In the fiddle there should:

```
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color:Red
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues here.

One, that jsfiddle is all on one line and wrapping.

Two, your CSS for the `ul` reads: `.nav-menu ul` -- `nav-menu` IS the `ul`, thus it should read:

```
.nav_menu { list-style: none; ... }
```

The reason the `background: red` isn't showing up is because the elements inside of the `<ul>`, the `<li>`s have `float: left` set. This removes from from the flow of the `<ul>` and effectively makes your `<ul>` have a height of 0. While there is more than one way to solve this problem, the quickest would be to add a `overflow: hidden` to the `<ul>`.

Comment: Thanks silly me, took me ages as a web designer to understand floats, 3 motnhs in as a c# programmer and ive forgotten"!

Answer (score 1):

**Define your** `.nav-menu li` `list-style:none;` and **define** your `.nav-menu` `overflow:hidden;`

**Add this css**

```
.nav-menu{
overflow:hidden;
}

.nav-menu li{
list-style:none;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PdZrt/1/)**